# How to change the state of an Action widget in an AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, state

I want to validate the user input and then enable the Dialog's Submit action.

Using StatefulBuilder inside the dialog's `content` doesn't work here, since the `actions` does not live in the `content` Widget.  So how would one go about changing a property on an `action` widget?

Currently my workaround is to not use `actions`, and have a Row of buttons inside the dialog's `content`, which is OK, but I'd like to know whether there is a better way.

I feel that using a Provider just to hold the "validation result" is a bit overkill.

EDIT: Example demonstrating that a StatefulBuilder allows only inner widgets to be updted with state changes.  The button sets `enabled`, but the of two "action buttons" only the one inside the StatefulBuilder is rebuilt.  The AlertDialog `actions` does not get updated.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dialogs'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text('Clickme'),
          onPressed: _dialogWithAction,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _dialogWithAction() async {
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        bool enabled = false;
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Add Address'),
          content: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerSetState) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Enable Submit'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    enabled = true;
                    innerSetState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    // This Workaround widget is rebuild by the stateSetter
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: enabled ? () => Navigator.pop(context) : null,
                      child: Text('Submit'),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // This Widget does not get rebuilt when "enabled" is changed
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Submit'),
              onPressed: enabled
                  ? () {
                      Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
                    }
                  : null,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post an excerpt of your code?

Comment: I will do a minimal example, I will just need a bit of time.